# How to make iOS app with 3D element?

Tags: ios, 3d

I want to make an app LIKE THIS https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1000413190, but I don't know how to make steps create it.

For example: connect app with fbx file or something ...., because I just code layout and other people will make 3D scene, so how can I connect them?

I am an mobile developer [ios, android, windowsphone] but I have never worked with 3d :(, I need an advice, please help me!

Comment: This question is far too broad. And instead of posting a link to some other app, update your question with clear, specific needs that you have. Also include details about what research you have done and what specific issues you have.

Comment: I just updated the question, please help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty obscure question. How do I... build a 3D app. My first response is... if you can't plan this out... then it's gonna be a tough journey my friend.
If you are a web dev, then you'll know the steps, minus the 3D.
I didn't download the app... so I'm making a few assumptions here.

GOAL: You can view different parts of the building in 3D and move around in them like a virtual tour.

You probably could dive right into Unity3D game engine and create 95% of the app. Unity builds to iOS, Android and others(and is super fun to play around with). Would allow you to build 3D simple and fast without the need for a lot of web services/plugins(aka programming something like Three.js, then Cordova to build native). So here's an off-the-hip outline of how I would tackle it.

1. Plan

   - Backend(server side API... whatever you chose to code in)

     - Database(mongo or postgresql are free, host on Heroku)?
     - Middleware (OAuth/Security, etc)
   - Web Services(client access to API, c# for Unity, can program on mac)

     - Login
   - Unity3D(client)

     - Menu
     - UI/UX
   - 3D

     - Building 3D environment
     - Rendering 3D environment
     - Walkthrough/User control/end/start/etc...
     - Animations
     - etc...
2. 3D Creation

   - Never worked with 3D before? Hire someone? Learn yourself?
   - Maya/3DStudio... or beginner I recommend Milkshape(Windows only).
   - Shaders: basic, mobile, how complex? what are your expectations? iPad? iPhone? Different devices render differently. Might need to create fallback shaders to get the desired look and feel for your environment.
3. Testing

   - Bug fixes, bug tracking, user feedback.
4. Deployment

   - Build to iOS through store.

That's all I have time to write. Hope that helps... GOOD LUCK!

Comment: Thank you very very much!!!!!

Comment: Could you please mark this as the answer? :) I'm trying to get my rep up for possible remote jobs. Much thanks!

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much!!! ^_^